# Android - How to insert HTML string into SQLite

Tags: android, html, sqlite, insert

In databaseHandler.java:

```
public void Exec(String strSQL) {
        OpenDB();
        db.execSQL(strSQL);
        CloseDB();
    }
```

Insert method:

```
 public void InsertData (int Id, String name, String content){
        int nr= db.CountRecord("select * from tbPosts where PostID="+Id+"");
        if(nr==0){
            db.Exec("insert into tbPosts values('"+Id+"','"+name+"','"+content+"')");
        }
    }
```

"Content" value include HTML string. When run application, Android Studio show:  syntax error..

Comment: Can you elaborate the error message you are getting and the exact line on which you are getting the error.

Comment: "Content" feild include special characters:  '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use ContentValues to insert your data so you dont have to escape your character in html format like "" or ''.

```
public void InsertData (int Id, String name, String content){
    int nr= db.CountRecord("select * from tbPosts where PostID="+Id+"");
    if(nr==0){
       ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
       cv.put("id",id);
       cv.put("name",name);
       cv.put("content",content);
       db.insert("tbPosts",null,cv);
    }
}
```

In your db helper class :

```
public void insert(String tableName, String additional, ContentValues values) {
   db.insert(tableName,null,values);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your comment! But, have error "cannot resolve method insert"

Comment: what is your db class?

Comment: no..its helper class..just create additional method to insert

Comment: Can you share me the method!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Id is integer so in the db.Exec command it should not be wrapped with ' "+id+" ' but with "+id+" only. Please provide the full error log if it doesn't fix your problem

Comment: Cái này lỗi ở cái content của em nó nó chứa dấu ' anh ạ!

Answer (score -1):

`Content` string contains non-allowed special characters. Quoting from java documentation:

> It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language. A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.

Anyways it is not good idea to store and query for HTML, what is your use case here. I am sure there would be better way of acheiving it.

Comment: My app is Health Care! My app get data from My Webservice. TbPosts (ID, Name, Content,..) Content feild (Tinymce input) include HTML string to show bold font, new line, images, align,..